# unable to send values from one activity to other in Android

Tags: android, android-bundle

I've created a bundle and put values onto it and jumped to the next activity,for some reason its not able to get the values at the other end,it says null object reference,but i have my values with me,

```
public void rsa_key(String s){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeClass.class);
        //Create the bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data to bundle
        //String hello=null;
        bundle.putString("id", txId);
        bundle.putString("cardamt", cardAmount);
        bundle.putString("cardconv", cardConvFee);
//Add the bundle to the intent
        intent.putExtras(bundle);




        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

In the other activity

```
String txId = bundle.getString("id");
        String cardConvFee = bundle.getString("cardconv");
        String cardAmount = bundle.getString("cardamt");
```

Comment: Where do you have that code in other activity. in onCreate. Also using a debugger should help

Comment: How are you getting the bundle of first activity in second activity? Please post your log, too.

Comment: I've put it outside OnCreate,i guess thats the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
public void rsa_key(String s){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeClass.class);

        //String hello=null;
        intent.putExtras("id", txId);
        intent.putExtras("cardamt", cardAmount);
        intent.putExtras("cardconv", cardConvFee);





        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

in your second activity onCreate method

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String txId = bundle.getString("id");
        String cardConvFee = bundle.getString("cardconv");
        String cardAmount = bundle.getString("cardamt");
```

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: ah,it should be inside OnCreate ??

Comment: yes..................

Answer (score 0):

Please convert integer values in string first and then send it to another activity.

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        //Add your data to bundle
        //String hello=null;
        bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(txId));
        bundle.putString("cardamt", String.valueOf(cardAmount));
        bundle.putString("cardconv", String.valueOf(cardConvFee));
```